# Is the symbol "is an element of" $\in$ applicable to elements of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

This question may sound juvenile, but I searched a lot on the Internet and can't make certain...

If $a_{ij}$ is an element of the matrix $A$, can I use the notation $a_{ij} \in A$? The problem is matrix $A$ is not a set. Is the symbol "$\in$" valid in this case?

Comment: No. I don't like this and hope it's not common.  But if you do see it somewhere it probably means what you want it to mean.

Comment: I disagree with Mauro completely: A matrix is not a set, and nobody uses $a \in A$ to mean that $a$ is an entry in the matrix $A$.

Comment: I also disagree with Mauro: the elements of a *matrix* come in a fixed order, whereas the elements of a *set* have no order. A matrix and its transpose are different matrices, but have the same underlying entries - just in a different order.

Comment: I fully agree with Rahul. I've never seen the usage $a \in A$ for the scenario where $A$ is a matrix and $a$ is an entry (or component) of $A$.

Comment: For what it's worth, I usually write "let $a_{ij}$ be the (i,j)-th entry of the matrix $A$" or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in a matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix},$$ the "entries" $a,b,c,d$ are not "elements" of $A$.

Similarly, in an ordered triple
$$
\mathbf{x} = (a,b,c)
$$
the "coordinates" $a,b,c$ are not "elements" of $\mathbf{x}$.

In a string
$$
\sigma = \text{"help"}
$$
the "letters" h,e,l,p are not "elements" of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

First, one refers to the *entries* of a matrix, and not the *elements* of a matrix since a matrix is not a set — this is the crux of the issue, as the symbol $`\in'$ is only appropriate in the context of sets.

One way to resolve this is the following: if $A= [a_{ij}]$ is an $m$-by-$n$ matrix with complex entries, one could define the elements of $A$ as the set $E(A):=\{ x \in \mathbb{C}\mid x = a_{ij},1\le i \le m, 1\le j \le n\}$. For example, if 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then $E(A) = \{ a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22}\}$. In this setting it is appropriate to write $`a_{ij} \in E(A)'$.